# Redirect from subdomains to pages in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to redirect from subdomains:

```
alpha.mydomain.com
beta.mydomain.com
*.mydomain.com
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/alpha.aspx
http://mydomain.com/beta.aspx
http://mydomain.com/*.aspx
```

in the

```
   void Application_BeginRequest Event
```

from the global.asax file

I want the webbrowser keep showing the subdomain url after the url.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need :)

[Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)